# In serenity BDD ,How to fix this problem?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd

In serenity BDD, throw an exception while running the chrome browser.

Not found a valid solution.

```
And fill up authentication credential and submit: # LoginStepDefinitions.fill_up_authentication_credential_and_submit(String,String>)
      net.thucydides.core.webdriver.exceptions.ElementShouldBeEnabledException: Expected enabled element was not enabled
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.WebElementFacadeImpl.waitUntilEnabled(WebElementFacadeImpl.java:1005)
```

It will open the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Expected enabled element was not enabled" - the element you are trying to interact with is not enabled (it might be a hidden element, or hidden by another element, or not the element you think it is).